# Join open postgresql transaction

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jasper-reports, jasperserver

Is there a way for getting and using an existing (open) transaction ?

I have an application using JPA/Hibernate that inserts some data. Within the session (and so the transaction), I want to generate some jasper reports from another server.
Jasper report uses its own query for getting data. But needed data are not yet commited.

So that's why I want jasper server get the transaction opened by JPA/Hibernate (with an id by example ?).

Thanks !

Comment: Were you able to sort this out? The docs below doesn't help much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the connection's transaction isolation level to one of the values described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html).

In Hibernate this is done in the session configuration by specifying a `hibernate.connection.isolation` as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html).

Comment: Thank you ! It seems to be exactly what I need. I will try that.